# How to install Firefox (to be ran in headless mode) on a Ubuntu non-desktop server with minimal dependencies?

Tags: server, firefox, gtk3, xvfb

I am using Ubuntu16 to host a Jenkins continuous integration server environment.

I need to host Firefox Headless mode which unfortunately still requires GTK3 to run. See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1372998

Judging from this ticket, the following packages appear to be necessary:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-0 libdbus-glib-1-2 xvfb
```

I get the feeling this might be more than I need to install. I really have to be minimal in what I install here.

Has anyone used Firefox headless on a non-Desktop Ubuntu server? What was the bare minimum you got Firefox Headless working with? Do I really need `xvfb`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off topic because there's an open upstream bug report for just this issue and it's extremely unlikely that anyone can work around it.

Comment: yes i totally agree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in [your linked bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1372998) it's currently impossible to build Firefox without hard dependencies on GTK3, Glib, D-Bus. The same goes for X11 (e. g. via X.org or Xvfb) on Linux.